# Java - how to find class and other level dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, external, resolve, identify

We would like to break a huge JAVA project [EAR] into multiple JARs. So in order to do that we need to find out the dependencies of a class inside an package with other classes [in other packages].

This structural analysis is complete in the sense that how class A is dependent upon other classes (A,B,C). But we would like to go a level further and find out what methods, constants defined in other files are being used in this class A. It would be really useful if the information can be extracted into say an excel format.

Any help in identifying this set would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) tool. It allows you to query package and class dependencies graphically.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of existing tools for this.
Use JDepend Eclipse plugin, its easy